# Chrome crashed, is jupyter notebook still running?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am working on some very lengthy calculations (8 hours). While doing these calculations, I was working on something else in chrome. Something went wrong on that website, and chrome shut down, where also my jupyter notebook file was running. Now I have started it back up and the logo is still indicates the program is running (it shows the hourglass icon), but I am not sure if this is actually true, in that case I would like to restart the program as quickly as I can.

Hope you guys can help! Thanks!

Comment: is there any way to know if the function is running or not?

Comment: You can see if your code is running by checking the system monitor: if there's a `python` process with high CPU consumption, it's probably still running. However, I think Jupyter cannot really reconnect to the running kernel, so if the result of the computation is only printed to stdout, you lost it the moment the web interface got disconnected.

Comment: Ah okay, It is still running, but what do you mean that it only printed to stdout? How do I know this?

Comment: I have these two lines in my terminal. The first one is the good one, the second one is the new one I guess, is there any way I can let it connect with the old one?

[I 20:57:12.340 NotebookApp] Starting buffering for afecf240-a4d7-4c0d-819b-223133252b9c:737d9b37f09641178abe10f2b7ffd713
[I 20:57:55.365 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel afecf240-a4d7-4c0d-819b-223133252b9c

Comment: Relevant [issue #641](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/641) and [issue #2833](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/2833).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just tested this on locally running Jupyter 4.4.0.

Cells submitted for running will complete as usual (assuming no exception occurs) as long as the kernel is still alive. After that computation is done, you can continue working on the notebook as usual. All changes to that kernel session are preserved, for example if you define a function or save your result in a variable, they will be available later. If you have it doing intensive computation, you can check your system monitor: `python` consuming lots of CPU means that it is probably still running.

If you have unsaved changes to your notebook, for example new code or cells, they will be lost. The code in them still seems to be executed though if it was set to run (Ctrl+Enter).

If you open [localhost:8888](http://localhost:8888) in a browser again, you should be able to see if the kernel is running (e.g. the hourglass icon). The running/idle detection seems to work fine upon reconnect.

However, the new browser session never gets updates from other sessions. This means that everything sent by the running code to the standard output (e.g. with `print`) after the disconnect is **irretrievably lost**, but you can still see what it printed before you got disconnected, assuming it was (auto-)saved. Once the kernel is done and you run cells from this new session, your browser will correctly get updates and display output as usual. Apparently ([#641](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/641), [#1150](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1150), [#2833](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/2833); thanks @unutbu) it is still not fixed due to Jupyter's architecture requiring a huge rework for that to function.

You can also attach a console with `jupyter console --existing your-kernel-session-uuid`, but it will not respond until the kernel is idle.